# MemoryError in Python when using sklearn .fit() and large sparse matrices (currently with boolean features)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

Here's the setup:

Number of classes: 1806

Training data length is 61499

Number of features is 40473 (these are boolean at the moment, although that will probably change at some point)

On average each training datum has ~10 1's in the row, and thus 40463 0's (i'm using scipy's sparse matrices).

I've tried a variety of learning algs (linearsvc gets the best performance, and sgdclassifier seems to be the most efficient with performance only slightly below that of linearsvc), and some dimensionality reduction (pca, svd), but I suspect that there's something wrong in the way that I'm setting up my matrix? (or perhaps there is just a better way, as this method does work when there are significantly less classes/features/data)

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

(Edit: also tried sgdclassifier's .partial_fit(), which even with two calls took excessively long, so I didn't let it finish)

Comment: You mentioned using PCA / SVD. Are you doing this in a way where the resulting matrix is still sparse? If you subtract the mean as is typically done in PCA, your matrix probably won't have any zeroes anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MemoryError typically occurs when you run out of addressable memory. If you are running 32-bit python, this error can often be avoided by using 64-bit python instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337560/loadmat-python-memory-error) for details on why this happens.

Comment: I upped it for more training data and hit a MemoryError again--> number of categories: 6578
training data length is 225065
number of features is 100529
errored at ~4.8 gb --any ideas (other than more ram) ?

Comment: Are you running both a 64-bit OS *and* 64-bit python? Also, how much RAM and swap space do you have? And to make sure I'm understanding your numbers, are you trying to create a data matrix that has `225065 * 1000529` elements?

Comment: yes / 6gb--tried on 8gm machine--just booted up an ec2 instance with 17gb, so we'll see (and yes, but I'm using sparse matrices)